# echo a php variable into innerhtml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, innerhtml

I have a problem in my code, I want to put $meaning variable into innerhtml of my di,here is my code:
searchinput.php:

```
<form action = "search.php" method = "post">
    <input name="word" id="word" type="text" maxlength="255" />
    <label for="word">word:</label></br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />

</form>
<div id = "meaning"> </div>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("project",$db);
    $word = isset($_POST["word"]) ? $_POST["word"] : "";
    $result = mysql_query("select meaning from vocabulary where word = '$word'");
    $fetchmeaning = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    $meaning = $fetchmeaning['meaning'];
?>
```

now I want to have this:

```
document.getElementById('meaning').innerhtml = $meaning; !!!!
```

how can I impelemt this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: "How to write a hello world in PHP?".

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Start a script tag after the definition of `$meaning` and put the below code in it.
Like.

```
document.getElementById('meaning').innerHTML = "<?PHP echo $meaning; ?>" ;
```

Also Can't you think of directly echo ing the value of `$meaning` inside the `div` without even using javascript? like

```
<div id = "meaning"><?PHP echo $meaning; ?></div>
```

You can also use the short form `<?=$meaning?>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="errorMessage"></div>
 <?php
  if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "User name or Password is incorrect";
  </script>';

  }
  ?>
```